# Converting bytes to GB with exact decimals in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The  first 2 columns have data in bytes. I am trying to convert it from Bytes to GB. For some reason its not reflecting properly in Free Space Column

```
    select vmi.VMTotalMaxSize, vmi.VMTotalSize, 
CONVERT(decimal(10,2),vmi.VMTotalMaxSize/1024/1024/1024) as [VMTotalMaxSize (GB)],
CONVERT(decimal(10,2),vmi.VMTotalSize/1024/1024/1024) as [VMTotalSize (GB)],
CONVERT(decimal(10,2),(vmi.VMTotalMaxSize-vmi.VMTotalSize)/1024/1024/1024) as [VMFreeSpace (GB)]
from tbl_WLC_VMInstance vmi

VM Total Max Size:375809638400, 268435456000, 214748364800
VMTotalSize: 375683809280, 62755176448, 74662805504
VMTotalMaxSize (GB): 350.00, 250.00, 200.00
VMTotalSize (GB):349.00, 58.00, 69.00   
VMFreeSpace (GB)0.00, 191.00, 130.00
```

It would nice to have the data with proper calculation. Thanks

Comment: Please give more details: show us a the structure of your table and the sql script you used

Comment: [duplicate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f119b518-6275-4188-a5be-3fa0fc967734/converting-bytes-to-gb-with-exact-decimals?forum=transactsql) posting is rude and wasteful

Comment: Is Stackoverflow and Microsoft Technet one single Entity? Is Stackoverflow owned by Microsoft? 

I DONT THINK SO! 

HENCE, DO NOT DISCOURAGE FELLOW IT GUYS!

Infact posting on both the ends provides a better chance to resolve the issue faster :)

If you do not have answer, please do not post...

Answer (score 7):

Divide by 1024.0, not 1024 - otherwise, your result is converted to integer thus losing decimal precision.

Comment: Dividing my an integer does not turn a decimal/float value to an integer. An expression only containing integers will return an integer; thus you end up with "integer math" (i.e. `9/10=0`). If either side is a `decimal` and the other an `int`, the result will be the same `10/9.0=10.0/9=1.111111`. In fact, using `1024.0` here actually implicitly converts the integer to a `decimal`; when the OP was using `1024` there was no conversion until the outer `CONVERT` (and by that stand, the integer math had been applied and the accuracy lost).

Comment: / 1024E / 1024E / 1024E - ISSUE RESOLVED.